# What does .delegate mean in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I found this code snippet:

```
def say = {println m}
say.delegate = [m:2]
say()
```

That apperantly prints 2. How does it work? Where can find documentation about `.delegate`? Google led me to the Delegate Transformation page that doesn't mention `.delegate` at all.

Comment: The google second page however does have documentation for it: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures#Closures-this%2Cowner%2Canddelegate . Hope this helps.

Comment: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-setting-closures.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The delegate of a closure is an object that is used to resolve references that cannot be resolved within the body of the closure itself. If your example was written like this instead:

```
def say = {
  def m = 'hello'
  println m
}
say.delegate = [m:2]
say()
```

It prints 'hello', because `m` can be resolved within the closure. However, when `m` is not defined within the closure,

```
def say = {
  println m
}
say.delegate = [m:2]
say()
```

the `delegate` is used to resolve the reference, and in this case the `delegate` is a `Map` that maps `m` to 2.

Comment: a handy way to provide default parameters to a closure: `def say = { def m = m ?: 'hello'; println m }`

Comment: @thenaglecode I think you meant this 

`def say = { def m = it ?: 'hello'; println m }`

Answer (score 14):

Three property of closures, are **this, owner, and delegate**, In general delegate is set to owner

```
def testClosure(closure) {
  closure()
}
testClosure() {
  println "this is " + this + ", super:" + this.getClass().superclass.name
  println "owner is " + owner + ", super:" + owner.getClass().superclass.name
  println "delegate is " + delegate + ", super:" + delegate.getClass().superclass.name

  testClosure() {
    println "this is " + this + ", super:" + this.getClass().superclass.name
    println "owner is " + owner + ", super:" + owner.getClass().superclass.name
    println "delegate is " + delegate + ", super:" + delegate.getClass().superclass.name
  }
}
```

prints

```
this is ConsoleScript0@11d20d3, super:groovy.lang.Script
owner is ConsoleScript0@11d20d3, super:groovy.lang.Script
delegate is ConsoleScript0@11d20d3, super:groovy.lang.Script
this is ConsoleScript0@11d20d3, super:groovy.lang.Script
owner is ConsoleScript0$_run_closure1@caea19, super:groovy.lang.Closure
delegate is ConsoleScript0$_run_closure1@caea19, super:groovy.lang.Closure
```

Comment: By default may be the owner, but what drives Groovy DSLs is the fact that you can reassign the delegate to any object