# How to access excel cell by column name with whitespace in POI/ExcelBuilder

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, builder

Thanks to http://www.technipelago.se/content/technipelago/blog/44
It's possible to access excel cell by through row iterator and the column name. But it seems that not possible to access by column name where the name contains white-space. Please give me some pointer on how to make it possible in the ExcelBulider context to access cell by even name with white-space. 
Here is the examples to illustrate:

```
new ExcelBuilder("customers.xls").eachLine([labels:true]) {
    print firsname // this already possible
    print <a column name with space> // I wish to have
}
```

where `firstname` is a column name. I wish it possible to access another column of name with space.

I could use a dictionary to encapsulate the mapping from column name to column inedx, to implement the logic of access by column outside of the ExcelBuilder, but I'd like it to be more encapsulated in one single place/logic in ExcelBuilder.

Maybe, I have not had enough knowledge of POI and Groovy's builder techniques.

Please help!

Thanks,

Yu

Comment: Unfortunately the contact information of the author of ExcelBulider cannot be found at the the above site. Otherwise, I might ask him for some hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
new ExcelBuilder("customers.xls").eachLine([labels:true]) {
    print firsname
    print delegate.'a column name with space'
}
```

Comment: Where can I find out the black magic of delegate? I've read "Groovy in Action", but not quiet understand the details of builder and meta programming, I guess the magic might come from there?

Comment: @YuShen Hiya! There's some info in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120949/what-does-delegate-mean-in-groovy) and in the [docs on Closures](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures).  As you can see in the `ExcelBuilder`, [on line 86](http://www.technipelago.se/content/technipelago/blog/44) they call `closure.setDelegate(this)`, so any call to `delegate` inside the `eachLine` closure will get the builder, so you can then get the property from it :-) Indeed, the `firstname` gets looked up in the delegate automatically