# Anybody to explain the magic of groovy closure / Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to understand a portion of code of my Jenkins's pipeline based on groovy DSL and closure.

I have a Jenkins file as follow:

```
foo {
  var1 = "foo value 1"
  var2 = "foo value 2"
}
```

I have a groovy script (foo.groovy in vars directory) in my Jenkins's shared lib:

```
def call(body) {
   def config = [:]
   body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   body.delegate = config
   body()

   println config.var1 // display foo value 1 : for me the magic is here !!
}
```

I want to understand the groovy / jenkins mechanisme that when the closure is called the map config is set with the variables var1 and var2.

I understand (nearly) the closure mechanisme and the delegate method, but how can we know that the affectation of the config map to the delegate field of the closure allow the construction of the map with the variables declared in my Jenkinsfile ?

I hope I am quite clear in my question ! :)

Regards,

Stef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a property is referenced within a closure, and that reference cannot be resolved within the closure, attempts are made to resolve it in various "places"

1. `this`
2. The closure's `delegate` property, which can be reassigned
3. The closure's `owner`

In your example, `var1` and `var2` are examples of references that cannot be resolved within the closure.

The following assigns the closure's delegate to `config` and ensures that this is the first "place" that will be used to resolve unresolved references

```
def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
```

Therefore, when we set the properties `var1` and `var2` within the closure, they are resolved against `config`, i.e. set as key-value pairs of this `Map`.

If your example was changed to:

```
foo {
   def var3 = "some value"

   var1 = "foo value 1"
   var2 = "foo value 2"
   var3 = "some value"
}
```

`var3` would *not* be resolved by `config` because it can be resolved within the closure.

### Update

In response to your comment which (I think) is asking: why does setting the closure's delegate to a map cause a key-value pair to be added to that map?

When `var1 = "foo value 1"` can't be resolved within the closure, it is resolved instead against the map, because of this

```
def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
```

so that effectively means we're calling

```
config.var1 = "foo value 1"
```

which is Groovy shorthand for

```
config.put("var1", "foo value 1")
```

Maybe it's a bit easier to understand if you change your code to call the `put` method directly, e.g.

```
def foo = {
  put('var1', "foo value 1")
}

def call(body) {
   def config = [:]
   body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   body.delegate = config
   body()

   println config.var1 // display foo value 1 : for me the magic is here !!
}

call(foo)
```

If you run this code in the Groovy Console, you'll see that it also prints "foo value 1".

If you're still struggling, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8120949/2648) will help.

Comment: thanks for the response but I still not understand how I know that a do assign a map object to the delegate field of my closure and what is the mecanisme in groovy that construct my map with the declared fields in my closure (for example if I assign a string object to the delegate field I think that will not work) ?